# My H1 is not changing colour and I cant figure out why. All of the other selectors are changing colour on command, but the H1 is not responding

Tags: html, css

I am a complete beginner so apologies if this is a silly issue ! Please see my code below. The H1 is not changing colour, I have seperated the CSS and HTML and linked them. When I target the menu class and paragraph selector the colours change as expected but the H1 is not changing colour. please help :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>MYWEBSITE</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container menu">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">About me</div>
        <div class="col-3">Contact Information</div>
        <div class="col-3">Certificates</div>
        <div class="col-3">gallery</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <h1>ROCHELLECODES</h1>
    <p>Welcome to my website</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
h1 {
  font-family: "Bebas Neue", sans-serif;
  color: lawngreen;
}
.menu {
  font-family: "Bebas Neue", sans-serif;
  color: blue;
}
p {
  font-family: "Bebas Neue", sans-serif;
  color: blueviolet;
}
```

I expected the H1 text "ROCHELLECODES" to turn "Lawngreen" as written in my CSS but nothing is happening. The other selectors are working normally.

Comment: Try right clicking it in a browser and picking "inspect" to open browser dev tools. Double check the style that is actually applied to the element.

Comment: Did you try inspect element the H1? Does its CSS show the color? Is the color property striked out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order in which the `<style>` and `<link>` tags appear in your HTML code matters.

The boostrap stylesheet is loaded after your stylesheet, and boostrap also has a rule for `h1` that overwrites your styling.

Just change the order in your HTML to:

```
    <title>MYWEBSITE</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
```

This won't always solve your problem because also [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) plays an important role. But having your style sheet after the one of the framework allows you to overwrite rules with the same Specificity.

Comment: that's fixed it. I totally see what you're saying will keep in mind in the future ! thanks alot :) x